# Correct use of the superlative degree

Tags: conjunctions, superlative-degree

Kindly tell me whether I used the superlative degree correctly in these two sentences:

1. He enjoyed all *the sweetest and         most charming* scenery.
2. He enjoyed all *the sweetest and **the** most charming* scenery.

Comment: Aside from "the the" never being correct, I'm not understanding what you mean by "degree".

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to the difference between 1) and 2), apart from 2) having "the" in front of "most".  Am I caffeine-deprived?

Comment: Is the use of *all* here part of the attempt to use the superlative degree? Because if it is, then you are using the degree incorrectly. If it isn't, then you are using the degree correctly, and also using *all* incorrectly for some other reason.

Comment: Unfortunately there is typing, I have corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

charming is not really use for scenery, but makes for a good metaphor.

If you want to use **most**, you could write:

He enjoyed the sweetest and most charming of scenery.

Comment: Charming would be normal enough of scenery.

Comment: I guess you are right there :), but along it sweet it was more metaphorical.